# json decoding of POST request failing in python

Tags: python, request

this error has been discussed in many threads and i tried all those before posting this question! none of them are solving my problem and i continue to get the same error. however the same url when opened in browser it does return a valid json response. only in my python code its failing.

so here is my code,

```
url = 'https://<some-site-name>'

headers = {'some headers'}

payload = {'some payload'}

req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(req.json()) **-> errors appears on this line**
```

below is detailed error log,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ssh/testcode/kpp_login.py", line 142, in <module>
print(req.json())

File "/home/ssh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",     line 896, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File "//home/ssh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson /__init__.py",  line 518, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/home/ssh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

File "/home/ssh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode

return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What's the req.status_code?